# can I call hyperlink in asp hiddenly?

Tags: asp-classic

How can I call a particular website API 
(e.g. http://example.com/web.asp?username=xxx&pass=xxx) using classic ASP?

Comment: on code behind, open this web page, but the call will not be hidden to the proxy, or the statistic log, and the password will travel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean creating an `HTTP Request` in **classic asp** : [MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927184623/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110100-1.shtml)